# ImageFont.textsize() seems wrong

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL to precompute the size that a given line of text will take at a given font and size. PIL seemed to be more or less the only working solution.

I tried to check results of `font.getsize()` by comparing it with the size of text typed into Adobe Illustrator. They very rarely seem to match.

I chose the following settings in Adobe Illustrator for my text:

- unit: `pt`
- tracking: `0`
- kerning: `auto`
- font size: `9`
- text content: a sequence of 25 "i"s

In the python REPL, I created fonts using the `ImageFont.truetype('...', 9)` instruction, then called `font.getsize('...')`, with the same text as in Adobe Illustrator

Numbers were different for all fonts that I tested except Arial:

```
| Font                | Width in Illustrator | Result with Pillow |
|---------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
| Arial               | 49.987               | 50                 |
| AppleGothic         | 35.774               | 26                 |
| Times New Roman     | 62.513               | 75                 |
| Museo Sans 700      | 60.074               | 50                 |
| StixIntegralsD Bold | 60.074               | 50                 |
```

Here are the versions of relevant software I used:

- OS: macOS 10.13.6
- Python: 3.6.5
- Pillow: 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I managed to understand and found out how to get the desired effect.

Thanks to Mark Setchell for helping me on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205954).

What I got to understand was that pillow only cares about pixels, not about resolution. Thus I need to multiply the font size I am giving it by the resolution I intend to print at, then divide the result by that resolution, and finally convert from pts to millimeters.

The final formula is `getfont('...', resolution * font_size).getsize('...')[0] / resolution * 0.352778`

Comment: Hey, can you explain me what is getfont?