# What is the unit of ImageFont.textsize() returned values?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL to precompute the size that a given line of text will take at a given font and size. PIL seemed to be more or less the only working solution.

I am not sure what is the unit of the returned value of `font.textsize(..)`. The [doc](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm) doesn't specify it.

The reason why I am asking is because I am confused by the returned values as mentioned here: [ImageFont.textsize() seems wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169054/imagefont-textsize-seems-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units are pixels, so it tells you how large a canvas you would need to accommodate the text.

There is no reason it should be the same as any other product's text size.

There is occasionally a small discrepancy of 3-4 pixels, probably as a result of anti-aliasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! In that case I don't really get how to compute the size of how much space a given text would take if printed. It seems that pillow assumes a given resolution?

Comment: Pillow is not in the least bit interested in print sizes or resolutions, it only works in pixels, the same as pretty much all image processing tools. You can make something 100 pixels wide or 1,000 pixels wide and the *dpi* is completely irrelevant until you come to print it. At that point, if you say you want 300 dpi, your 100 pixels will print at 1/3 inch and your 1,000 pixels will print at 3.3 inches. *dpi* is just a number you can change at any point - the true measure of how much *"quality"* you have is how many pixels you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! I guess I can find out which resolution my supplier uses for printing, and thus the number of pixels I have. I know the font size I use, which is 9 pt. However it seems like I should in some way multiply that by the resolution, and pass the result to pillow as font size? Otherwise, if I just pass 9 to pillow, it seems that the result would not take into account the amount of pixels I have available. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks again very much for your help

Comment: Yes, exactly... you seem to have the idea of it now.

Comment: Awesome!

I have managed to get the computation I wanted! The result was not that logical though. I had to multiply font size by resolution, divide result by resolution, and then the result seemed to be in `pt`s. In order to get millimeters I had to multiply by `0.352778`.

Thus final formula was: `getfont(‘...’, resolution * font_size).getsize(‘...’)[0] / resolution * 0.352778`.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: hey, how you got the resolution?